# How do I create a rotated Rectangle hitbox that detects a collision?

Tags: java, rotation

I have managed to create a rotated shape that detects collision using AffineTransform.getRotateInstance and createTransformedShape methods, and then using the intersects method of Affine Transform. However, I want a rotated Rectangle object(instead of rotated shape) that detects a collision while it is rotated.

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: I had asked the question before but it was not answered efficiently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069321/how-can-i-make-rotating-hitboxes-that-detect-collision